# Check if file is being run on server

Tags: php

I have a html file which has a link to php file. When i run the html file and click on php link source code of page is being shown as i'm not running on server. Is there a way we can check whether it is running on server and show a message like "Please run it on server" instead of showing source code. Searched a lot but didn't find anything on this topic . How can i do this?

Comment: What is your situation here? Why is this a possibility in the first place?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have a html file and i dont want the user to run it on server in order to view it ,contains some readme. The php file has some database query that is optional. So i wanted user to run it on server if he wants that one section to run ie query.php

Comment: But why does the user end up in the situation of having a PHP file on their local drive in the first place? Isn't that what the real problem is?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Its a documentation file

Answer (score 3):

No. If there's no PHP interpreter installed there's no way to run PHP script to check that and tell you that you need PHP interpreter installed first to run PHP script....

Answer (score 2):

actually you cannot check this, but you can make some kind of workaround

at the very top of your php file add following code:

```
<?php
if (false) {
    ?><script>
    alert('php is not on server!!!');
    document.location.href='http://MYSERVERADDRESS/';
    </script><?php
}
```

Comment: Should this have a closing php tag after the closing bracket?

Comment: @finiteloop no, it is better to avoid closing `?>` tag in PHP

Comment: @IlyaBursov correction: it should be avoided only if it is the be last element in the file, not in general

Comment: Fair point, but that code will not be at the end of the file. It will be followed by either more php or markup

Comment: @llya Bursov Is there a Jquery solution, When i jump from html to Php via link? tried this still showing source code

Comment: This will simply print the <?php if(false) ... etc just like the op's original code.

Comment: of course, if user is able to open php file locally - he/she already has source code and can view it, and there is no possibility to prevent this at all, but it will hide code from some users :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski as soon as it is better to avoid mixing PHP with HTML, we usually have situation with single opening `<?php` and no `?>` at all, but of course correction is correct :)

Comment: @Ace you can change `</script>` to `</script><div style="display:none;">` - this will hide rest of page in browser

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Sure, for sport I can think of something, but really, you shoudn't be in this situation.

sporthack: what you are trying to do is make non-interpreted code be hidden, and an error be shown. Be sure to realise the non-interpreted code will always be there in your source, so you have to 'hide' it.

Make all content available only via javascript. Also, define a javascript tag with a var via a php `echo` command.
Then, only show your code when the javascript var is set, otherwise show your desired error. Make sure all your code is 'behind' an include, so you don't show that.

Yeah. this'll take a bit of work to make pretty, so you'd be hard-pressed to even get it off the ground.